# I am getting a promise in return of a fetch call in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to get a json file in return.

this is a **fetch Function** i am using

```
handleApi(){
    return 
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson.movies;
        })
}
```

this function is being called on an button click event.

```
handleSubmit() {
    console.log(
        this.handleApi();
    )
```

but i am **getting this Promise** object in return not expected data

> Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}_40: 0_55: null_65: 0_72: null__proto__: Object

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise that's how it works. You need to move `console.log` in `this.handleApi().then(console.log)`

Comment: for me, I was missing the return in front of the fetch. Adding that solved my issues

Answer (score 5):

A more simplified

```
handleApi(){
    return 
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then(response => 
                response.json().then(jsonObj => return jsonObj.movies)
            )
}
```

then in handleSubmit

```
handleSubmit() {
    this.handleApi().then(movies => {
        console.log('Print list of movies:', movies);
    });
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code as following:

```
handleApi(){
return 
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson.movies;
        })
}
```

and

```
handleSubmit() {
 this.handleApi().then(function(movies) {
    console.log('Print list of movies:', movies);
 });
}
```